# xml error due to servlet file Cannot find the declaration of element , Referenced file contains errors

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, jsp, servlet-3.0

i don't know why these error occured can someone explain me how to solve them -

1. `cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web_1:web-app'.`
2. `Referenced file contains errors (jar:file:/C:/Program Files/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.standard.schemas_1.2.0.v201101142102.jar!/dtdsAndSchemas/web-app_2_5.xsd).  For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View and select "Show Details..."`

these are the two errors which i face and that because i added a servlet by mistake of which i intended to add a normal class file to my project ..
then both these error starting to show even i delete the servlet file .
this is my xml code (actually it is the basic code)- as i have not used a single servlet file untill yet , i only used jsp file.

still xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web_1:web-app
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
        xmlns:web_1="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID"
        version="3.0">
        <display-name>InitialD</display-name>
        <web_1:welcome-file-list>
            <web_1:welcome-file>index.html</web_1:welcome-file>
            <web_1:welcome-file>index.htm</web_1:welcome-file>
            <web_1:welcome-file>index.jsp</web_1:welcome-file>
            <web_1:welcome-file>default.html</web_1:welcome-file>
            <web_1:welcome-file>default.htm</web_1:welcome-file>
            <web_1:welcome-file>default.jsp</web_1:welcome-file>
        </web_1:welcome-file-list>
    </web_1:web-app>
```

Comment: if you need any other files .. please tell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark and Saurabh said, it is workable to remove every instance of "web_1:" from your web.xml file. Meantime it is better to remove the reference to the schema "xmlns:web_1". A workable snippet based on Saurabh's problem as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>InitialD</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

Comment: Just as a heads up, XML/HTML tags don't show up in an answer unless they're either escaped with backticks (`) or if the entire line is indented by four spaces.

Comment: This worked.  In my case, the problem was that I had version 2.5 and the error emerged when I downloaded some new eclipse server packages.  But your snippet fixed it because our snipped is version 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

Remove every instance of "web:" from your web.xml file.

Comment: you mean web_1 from the xml file

Comment: thank you for the answer .. it worked for me .. as i cannot vote u ( sorry for that )
but now it works fine .. thank you again ..